# FullCalendarJS: changing select event color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm working on FullcalendarJS and I want a darker color when I am selecting a date/time on a week view

[image]

as you can see from the image above, when I am selecting a date range, the highlight is not that visible I want it to be visible like the blue one highlighted dated today.

I tried to change the css on the select event property but it only changes when after the selection.

here's my code:

```
 $('.calendar').fullCalendar({
  header : {
        left:   'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right:  'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    timezone: 'local',
    defaultView : 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot : false,
    eventOverlap: false,
        select: function(start, end, event, view, resource) {
        $(".fc-highlight").css("background", "#00004c");
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing the color of the `fc-highlight` `CSS` class during the `select` event, just declare the following in your `CSS` in order to override it:

```
.fc-highlight {
   background-color: #00004c;
}
```

Also, make sure to set `selectable: true` in your `fullCalendar` config. since it defaults to `false` *- according to the API documentation -* and must be `true` if you want to select by clicking or dragging *(I am pointing this out since I can't see it in the provided code snippet).*

**Example:**

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
     left: 'prev,next today',
     center: 'title',
     right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },
   timezone: 'local',
   defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
   allDaySlot: false,
   eventOverlap: false,
   selectable: true
});
```

As you can see, the `select` event function is not needed anymore unless you want to perform any action at that point.

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4nb4gpnL/